# Ethers.JS V6 WebSocketProvider keeps disconnecting after some hours

Tags: websocket, ethers.js

so I upgraded to Ethers.JS V6 recently and am having some issue with their WebSocketProvider. So previously on V5 I had a keepAlive script that would detect the disconnection/timeout of the websocket and would then close it and reconnect.

In V6 I do not see a clear way to listen for disconnects or do a ping command to the websocket. I tried doing provider.on() but this version is very strict on what events you can listen for.

This is my code to create the connection

`function CreateSocketConnection(){ console.log("Creating Websocket connection..."); const socket = new w3cwebsocket(`${config.WEB_SOCKET_URL}${config.ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`);
return socket;
}

function main(){
const provider = new ethers.WebSocketProvider(CreateSocketConnection as WebSocketCreator);
}

main();`

What is the recommended way to keep this socket connection alive? After 4 hours it no longer can log the new "block" events. Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue?